# How to receive tuple as an argument to a function in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, gauss

I have some code that was working fine in python2. I need to translate it to python3.
There is one piece of it that I can't understand how to adapt.

Here is some code.

**Function with error**

```
def gauss((x, y), x0, y0, intens, sigma):
    return intens*numpy.exp(-(numpy.power(x-x0, 2)+numpy.power(y-y0, 2))/(2.*sigma**2)).ravel()
```

**Caller function**

```
def dofwhm(psfdata):
    x = numpy.arange(psfdata.shape[1])
    y = numpy.arange(psfdata.shape[0])
    x, y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss, (x, y), psfdata.ravel(), p0=[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2, psfdata[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2], 5.0])

    return 2.355*abs(popt[3])
```

**The error that I get is**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catalog.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cutPsf
  File "/Users/igor/GALPHAT/pypygalphat/preprocessingNew/cutPsf.py", line 9
    def gauss((x, y), x0, y0, intens, sigma):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can somebody help me how to adapt it for python3?

UPDATE:
Well, @hpaulj answer seems to be right. I found that there are routine to convert Python2 code to Python3 code. After running on target file 2to3 -w cutPsf.py as a result I get the suggested solution from hpaulj. Unfortunately it results in fallowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catalog.py", line 323, in <module>
    cutPsf.run(tempDir+galaxy.psffile, outDirFits+galaxy.psffile)
  File "/Users/igor/GALPHAT/pypygalphat_p3/preprocessingNew/cutPsf.py", line 63, in run
    coeffwhm = dofwhm(newPsf)
  File "/Users/igor/GALPHAT/pypygalphat_p3/preprocessingNew/cutPsf.py", line 20, in dofwhm
    psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2, psfdata[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2], 5.0])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

As said before, everything runs perfectly with Python2...

Comment: Is the `def gauss((x, y), x0,...` your code, or from an imported library?

Comment: @hpaulj can't say for sure, Im not the author...

Comment: In py2, `/` is integer divide; in py3 the result may be float. `//` does integer divide.  The `/2` in `psfdata[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2]` is probably causing the problem.  Also newer `numpy` is pickier about indexing with floats; older versions tended to let that slide.

Comment: Yeah, // instead of / works only. Maybe it would be nice to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do the unpacking later

```
def gauss(xy, x0, y0, intens, sigma):
    x, y = xy
    return intens*numpy.exp(-(numpy.power(x-x0, 2)+numpy.power(y-y0, 2))/(2.*sigma**2)).ravel()
```

---

I suggested this based on the typical `scipy` optimized requirements, where the user defined function is called with `f(x, *args)`, where `x` is the variable (possibly array) that is optimized.  But `curve_fit` is different.

```
scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None,...)
```

Where the `f` (your `gauss`?) satisfies:

```
ydata = f(xdata, *params) + eps
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

I guess my suggestion is still valid if `xdata` is the `(x,y)` tuple, or array made from that. And `ydata` is `psfdata.ravel()`.

Comment: I had updated the op with results of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some modification with * operator.

```
def gauss(x, y, x0, y0, intens, sigma):
    return intens*numpy.exp(-(numpy.power(x-x0, 2)+numpy.power(y-y0, 2))/(2.*sigma**2)).ravel()

def dofwhm(psfdata):
    x = numpy.arange(psfdata.shape[1])
    y = numpy.arange(psfdata.shape[0])
    x, y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss, *(x, y), psfdata.ravel(), p0=[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2, psfdata[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2], 5.0])

    return 2.355*abs(popt[3])
```

Comment: After your sucesstions: im getting popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss, *(x, y), psfdata.ravel(), p0=[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2, psfdata[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2], 5.0])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gauss, x, y, psfdata.ravel(), p0=[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2, psfdata[psfdata.shape[1]/2, psfdata.shape[0]/2], 5.0])
Can you expand (x, y) as x, y directly in opt.curve_fit function?